Does bond enthalpy apply to solid to liquid state changes
I'm performing an experiment in which I melt certain substances, record the heat they melt, convert that heat to kJ per mole per each substance and then compare those found values to the already known bond enthalpies. I only just now had the question on if all bonds break from solid to liquid, or if only certain do.

Ionic or molecular substances?

Has liquid water less bonds than solid water?

Only intermolecular bonds (between molecules) are broken, not covalent ones, and I would assume you are not melting salts but covalent compounds, but see Karsten's point. If a salt it is more complicated.

Heat of fusion sometimes does involve rearrangement of covalent or ionic bonds. In fact, the relationship between melting and bonding can get quite complicated because both "intermolecular forces" and "covalent/ionic bonds" are ultimately the same type of interaction, electrostatic forces.
Consider our old friend water and its hydrogen bonding. Molecular-orbital theory understands hydrogen binding as a delocalization of covalent bonds into formally intermolecular linkages, and the melting of ice (in which all water molecules are hydrogen-bonded to one another) involves breaking some of these delocalized linkages. No bonds are formally broken, but they are rearranged with some loss of delocalization and the resulting energy cost enters into the relatively large heat of fusion of water. Comparison of bond lengths in solid versus gaseous iodine indicates a similar type of delocalized-bond rearrangement when that element is melted or sublimed.
We move on from there. Certain materials that are molecular when fluid form ions in the solid phase, as with phosphorus pentabromide forming $\ce{PBr4^+}$ and $\ce{Br^-}$ ions in its solid phase. Then melting involves breaking ionic bonds in exchange for making new covalent ones.
Among the greatest examples of bond rearrangement upon fusion are the lighter Group 14 elements. Silicon and germanium have the diamond-like semiconducting structure we know and love only as solids; this structure lacks the mobility needed to survive in a liquid phase and these elements end up becoming metals when melted. In the case of silicon the volume contraction associated with this structural change beats that of water. And then there is carbon, whose liquid phase is accessible only at tens of MPa pressure and thousands of Kelvins; this phase is not fully characterized and we can't really tell what bonding changes are involved in a melting process that must involve quite high energy input.
